# Autoscroll div with jQuery to the bottom after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrolltop

I have a div class='messages'. I add date to this div via jQuery.append()
Here are the styles:

```
.messages {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
padding:10px;
height: 400px;
overflow-x:visible;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
font-size:14px;
}
```

For autoscroll I use such function:

```
receiveMessage = function (name, message, type) {
    //adding new message
    $("#messages").append('<strong>' + name + ": " + '</strong>' + message + '<br>');
    /autoscrolling to the bottom
    $("#messages").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#messages").height()
    }, 300);
}
```

About ~20 messages are scrolling normally, but after it 'hangs', new messages are not scrolled. Chrome Version 19.0.1084.56 . What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide the HTML or better yet create a Test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: `#messages` and `.messages`- did you mix them up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
scrollTop: $("#messages").height()
```

to

```
scrollTop: $("#messages").scrollHeight
```

Comment: actually, now( This worked: $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast"); I've tried to answer my own question but it isn't shown

Comment: @f1nn your solution does work. I tried out your 'accepted answer', but that doesn't seem to do the work.

Answer (score 3):

This solution did not work for me, however, the following did...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#chat-scroll').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#chat-scroll').get(0).scrollHeight}, 2000); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#chat-scroll').animate({scrollTop: $('#chat-scroll')[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: this is IMHO the simplest/best answer, for current versions of jQuery. works fine in a single line of code, thx